# openssl create Pbkdf2 key derivation

Tags: openssl, pbkdf2

I want to derivate a hashed password using the Pbkdf2 algorithm.

```
Input: Password, Salt, HashAlgorithm, IterationCount
Output: Hash
```

How to perform this with the openssl command line? I found https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/EVP_KDF-PBKDF2.html, so openssl should be able to do it, but I cannot find any docs on which command line to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the OpenSSL "kdf" app to do this. You will need OpenSSL 3.0 for this (that app is not available in earlier versions).

See the man page here:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-kdf.html

Example:

```
$ openssl kdf -keylen 32 -kdfopt digest:SHA256 -kdfopt pass:password -kdfopt salt:salt -kdfopt iter:10000 PBKDF2
5E:C0:2B:91:A4:B5:9C:6F:59:DD:5F:BE:4C:A6:49:EC:E4:FA:85:68:CD:B8:BA:36:CF:41:42:6E:88:05:52:2B
```